# Python multiprocessing ending with zombies

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

36 000 targets are to be processed on an ubuntu. After 13-14 hours of calculation and 5814 targets, the number of processes (initally 120) drops and processes are becoming zombies.

I implemented Multiprocessing like this :

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import gc
import traceback

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from scrapy.settings import Settings
crawler_settings = Settings()
crawler_settings.setmodule(my_settings)

from scrapy.spiders.sales import SalesSpider

def format_target(seller):
    return f"xxxxxxxxxxx{seller}xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

def launch_crawler(crawler, seller):
    try:
        formated_seller = format_target(seller[1])
        if formated_seller:
            process = CrawlerProcess(crawler_settings)
            process.crawl(crawler, seller[0], formated_seller, seller[2])
            process.start(stop_after_crawl=True)
            del formated_seller
            del process
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

def process_x(urls_lst, process_nb):

    list_process = [None] * process_nb
    while urls_lst:
        for i in range(process_nb):
            if not (list_process[i] and list_process[i].is_alive()):
                list_process[i] = Process(target=launch_crawler, args=(SalesSpider, urls_lst.pop(0)))
                list_process[i].start()
                gc.collect()
                break

    ## Wait all thread end
    for process in list_process:
        if process:
            process.join()
            gc.collect()

## MAIN
sellers = [...] ## 36k objects
process_x(sellers,120)
```

This is the first time it happens with this implementation. I've already make it run over multiple days and going to end full without any problem.

How to prevent this ?

**Attempt 1**

```
def format_target(seller):
    return f"xxxxxxxxxxx{seller}xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

def launch_crawler(crawler, seller):
    try:
        formated_seller = format_target(seller[1])
        if formated_seller:
            process = CrawlerProcess(crawler_settings)
            process.crawl(crawler, seller[0], formated_seller, seller[2])
            process.start(stop_after_crawl=True)
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__=="__main__":
    
    n_cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    processes =  int(math.ceil(2.5 * n_cpu))

    sellers = get_sellers()         ## Returning psycopg2.extras.Record, can't pickle
    sellers = [[seller[0],seller[1],seller[2]] for seller in sellers]

    chunksize, remainder = divmod(len(sellers), processes)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes)
    pool.imap_unordered(partial(launch_crawler, SalesSpider),
                        sellers,
                        chunksize=chunksize)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Leading to error :

```
[INFO] Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-11-30 15:51:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraping/ebayspy/main.py", line 320, in launch_crawler
    process.start(stop_after_crawl=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 327, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1317, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1299, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(cast(ReactorBase, self))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 843, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the following section of code:

```py
            if not (list_process[i] and list_process[i].is_alive()):
                list_process[i] = Process(target=launch_crawler, args=(SalesSpider, urls_lst.pop(0)))
```

If `list_process[i]` is not `None` but the process has terminated, then `list_process[i].is_alive()` will return `False` and the complete boolean expression being tested by your if statement will be `True` and you will end up replacing `list_process[i]` with a new `Process` instance *having never joined the process that had previously been  referenced by `list_process[i]`*. This will lead to zombie processes. So modify the code as follows:

```py
            p = list_process[i]
            if not (p and p.is_alive()):
                if p:
                    p.join()
                list_process[i] = Process(target=launch_crawler, args=(SalesSpider, urls_lst.pop(0)))
```

**Update**

If you have a good reason to run `scrapy` in parallel, then using a multiprocessing pool might go a long way to solving your zombie problems. Set `N_PROCESSES` to the number of concurrent processes that you want. Since the `scrapy` processes are largely waiting for network requests to complete, there is no reason why this number cannot be larger than the number of CPU cores you have. But be aware that processes do take up a lot of resources, such as memory. So 120 processes *might* be *excessively* large.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import traceback
from functools import partial

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.spiders.sales import SalesSpider

crawler_settings = Settings()
crawler_settings.setmodule(my_settings)


def format_target(seller):
    return f"xxxxxxxxxxx{seller}xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

def launch_crawler(crawler, seller):
    try:
        formated_seller = format_target(seller[1])
        if formated_seller:
            process = CrawlerProcess(crawler_settings)
            process.crawl(crawler, seller[0], formated_seller, seller[2])
            process.start(stop_after_crawl=True)
            del formated_seller
            del process
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sellers = [...] ## 36k objects
    N_PROCESSES = 120 # Really this many?
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(len(sellers), 4 * N_PROCESSES)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    pool = Pool(N_PROCESSES)
    pool.imap_unordered(partial(launch_crawler, SalesSpider),
                        sellers,
                        chunksize=chunksize)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: After testing, another error pops :     assert self._popen is not None, 'can only join a started process'
AssertionError: can only join a started process (on p.join())

Comment: When you add a process to `list_process[i]` the very next statement is `list_process[i].start()`. So I don't see how you can have any un-started processes in `list_process`.  Your `AssertionError` seems to suggest that the exception is occurring elsewhere. Have you looked at your stack trace carefully?

Comment: How can I look my stack trace ? Sorry I am not familiar with this. I am currently running with this :  while urls_lst:
  for i in range(process_nb):   p = list_process[i]
   if not (p and p.is_alive()):
    list_process[i] = Process(target=launch_crawler, args=(SalesSpider, urls_lst.pop(0)))
    list_process[i].start()
    if p:
     p.join()

Comment: The stack trace is the list of line numbers and statements leading to the exception, specifically **assert self._popen is not None, 'can only join a started process' AssertionError: can only join a started process**. Some of these statements will be in your code and others might be in functions that your code calls depending on where the exception is called. See what statement in your program led to the exception.

Comment: But I have questions for you: I am not that familiar with `Scrapy`, but doesn't it have built-in support for crawling multiple URLs where it handles all the multithreading for you so do really need to be creating multiple processes yourself? And if you felt there was a need to, why not use multithreading instead since these crawls seem to be suitable for multithreading (that's what `Scrapy` uses).

Comment: `Scrapy` is single-threaded, built on top of [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation). According to this [article](https://medium.com/c%C3%B3digo-ecuador/python-multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-web-scrape-stock-price-history-faster-b72827601cf6), multithreading is faster and more efficient than multiprocessing because scraping is all about I/O, parsing data is not greedy. I've tried a while on implementing multithreading with scrapy but I wasn't able to use `twisted.internet.reactor` over different threads (there can be only one reactor per process), so I use multiprocess

Comment: FYI, I still have zombies with the last implementation I shared in the coments

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed update. I implemented the exact same code as your proposition, but unfortunately nothing happens as if the code just do not run. I use an AWS EC2 (ubuntu) from the [r5 family](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/ec2/instance-types/) so the ressources are not a problem. I am also trying to implement a Multiprocessing pool and launching subprocesses to launch `scrapy crawl SalesSpider` but nothing happens the same way

Comment: Nevermind the error was the following : _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'psycopg2.extras.Record'>: attribute lookup Record on psycopg2.extras failed. I created a list and the multiprocessing runs OK. The new problem is that when the Scrapy spider has finished : twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable. I'll try to use `subprocess` to spawn a new Python process